# Elipses no cambian de color en UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, raspberry-pi

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Raspberry Pi, usando Windows IoT. Especificamente, estoy haciendo un semáforo con leds y en la pantalla de mi app también dibujé un semáforo con elipses. Las elipses "apagadas" deben tener el color lightgray y "encendidas" sus correspondientes colores (verde, amarillo y rojo). Con un Timer voy haciendo que se repita todo el proceso para simular un semáforo trabajando eternamente.

El código hecho es el siguiente:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GpioPin LedVerde;
    GpioPin LedAmarillo;
    GpioPin LedRojo;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        GpioController gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
        //configuración de los pines
        LedRojo = gpio.OpenPin(23);
        LedAmarillo = gpio.OpenPin(24);
        LedVerde = gpio.OpenPin(25);
        LedVerde.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        LedAmarillo.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        LedRojo.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LedAmarillo.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LedRojo.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

    }
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        LedRojo.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        LedVerde.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LuzVerde.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        LedAmarillo.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        LuzAmarilla.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
        Task.Delay(1500).Wait();
        LedAmarillo.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        LuzAmarilla.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        LedRojo.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        LuzRoja.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);

    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto la aplicación, los leds se cambian de forma correcta, pero las elipses no, sólo la roja pasa de ser lightgray a red al final del timer y no vuelve a apagarse.

Comment: Desconociendo que tipo de objetos son LuzRoja, LuzAmarill y LuzVerde, parece ser que solo ves la ejecución de la ultima linea del timer_tick. Prueba a actualizar el dibujado de las elipses cada vez que uses Fill por si es un problema con el refresco de pantalla.

Comment: Son los objetos ellipses de UWP

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.ellipse